# Can I use expanding spray foam to support a cracked bathtub?

Tags: bathroom

I want to use spray foam to support tub. When using foam to support cracked tub wont foam push tub up. Tub is already cracked and wont hold water.

Comment: If the tub is already cracked & won't hold water, what is your overall goal here? Adding support (whether expanding spray foam or something else) isn't going to repair the crack and make it hold water.

Comment: Where is the crack? On the side or bottom?

Comment: be wary of foam, i filled the void under my tub, and it ended up swelling the tub.. the expansion rate is pretty powerful.  - your question needs elaboration, dont know where the crack is, and what you intent the foam to do.

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt that spray foam will provide much support. In addition to the tub itself, water is **heavy** - ~ 8 lbs./gallon - and you could easily have 50 gallons, > 400 lbs. of water in a bathtub.

Foam is great for insulation (because of the trapped air), and depending on the type of usage, can be very good for filling cracks. But unless it were specifically engineered to do so, I would not expect any consumer foam to be able to support any significant weight. If you were to fix the crack properly first (in the case of a bathtub (or anything with a liquid) foam would not normally be enough to seal the crack by itself), I would make sure there was plenty of support to prevent future movement == future cracks. Foam, in this context, is filler and not support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no is the answer. Definitely yes if you use the right foam, a structural foam (can hold up to 580 psi). There are different types of foam, open cell and closed cell. Never use open cell because there is no structure. It is spongy and not resistant to water absorption. Some closed cell foams are spongy too so you must select a minimum of 4 lb foam but 8 pound is much better. It is a 2 part foam that must be mixed and very quickly installed. Foam expands (4x to 30x depending upon density) so if not done right it will ruin your tub. My advise is to let a professional do it.